# Getting Force close error on Google Maps while zooming and panning

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, pan

Hi getting the following error while zooming and panning google maps. Kindly tell what could be the possible reason

```
                      07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:401)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:414)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.google.android.maps.StreetViewRenderer.getOverlay(StreetViewRenderer.java:149)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.google.android.maps.StreetViewRenderer.renderTile(StreetViewRenderer.java:86)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.google.android.maps.AndroidTileOverlayRenderer.renderTile(AndroidTileOverlayRenderer.java:62)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawTile(Unknown Source)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMap(Unknown Source)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.drawMap(MapView.java:1048)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:486)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6739)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1872)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1422)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1167)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 19:50:02.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3259):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried all the possile solutionn explained on stack overflow by overriding ondraw method in itemised overlay. Still the problem is coming. Please tell if anybody knows the solution
Thanks
Astha

Answer (score 1):

Without any code it will be hard to help you find out what you did wrong.

Based on the Exception itself, it seems like you have a memory leak. You can read some information about memory leaks on
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html